# Visual Studio Codeで同じファイルを開いた場合に読み取り専用にしたい

Tags: vscode

Visual Stdio Codeで同じファイルを開いた時に後から開いたユーザは読み取り専用になるような設定はありますでしょうか。

追記

環境は、Linux系のOSでVisual Stdio Codeからsshで複数ユーザがログインして編集するような作業になります。
現状vimを使用しているユーザから、同じファイルを開いて読み取り専用にならないのは困るとの指摘がVisual Stdio Codeを導入する障壁になっています。
個人的には、運用を変えろと思うところなんですが。

Comment: 状況設定がよく分からなかったのですが、たとえば何かしらの方法でネットワーク内でファイルを共有していて、同じファイルをネットワーク越しに複数のユーザーが編集する可能性がある、ということでしょうか。どんな環境（OSや共有方法など）を想定してらっしゃるのかを質問文に書いてくださるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

完全な回答にはならないかもしれませんが、参考までに投稿してみます。

「使用するエディタ(アプリ)」と「OSまたはファイルシステム」、それぞれの事情が絡んでくるので簡単には解決しないかもしれません。

希望している通り、別のプロセスが該当のファイルを既に開いている場合には、読み取り専用で開くエディタも(Windowsでは)ありますが、一方で Vim に関してはスワップファイル (`*.swp`) を作成することでロック状態を管理しています。

共有ファイルに対して異なるエディタを使っている場合、排他制御の方法に違いがあるとうまく処理できない気がします。